# Webdevelopement : Login Specification

Tags: php, authentication

I've just started with PHP and I want to implement a login.

Rather than re-inventing the wheel, is there any Online Specification for a login system?

Things I want to implement:

- detect Brute Force attacks
- implement password recovery
- maybe openID and/or with facebook account
- prevent SQL injection

So I think this has been done more than 1000 times. Where can I read about it?

Comment: If you're using Facebook login, then password recovery, brute force protection, and SQL injection has been taken care of. I personally prefer to use Facebook login or openID or similar whenever possible (and approved by the client) for this very reason. Why reinvent the wheel? :)

Answer (score 0):

See the [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) website.

Some packages you may be interested in are [Auth](http://pear.php.net/package/Auth) and [OpenID](http://pear.php.net/package/OpenID).